# Grub2 boots into prompt instead of menu after grub2-install

Tags: centos, grub2

This all starts when one day out of pure curiosity I ran "grub2-install" and it finished with no errors, although I expected no change either since I had in no way messed with grub modules. I had added an option to grub.cfg the legitimate way using 40_custom and then grub2-mkconfig but it had nothing to do with this, right? Well next time I boot into grub I see a prompt instead of a menu. After messing around a little I figure out that all I have to do is type "normal" to get to the menu and then I can continue as usual, this fixes my panic but I don't get what grub2-install did and how to fix it permanently! Every time I reboot now I see the prompt and have to enter the normal command for it to take me to the menu. I don't even know what normal does but it works. Is it a command that should execute by default but it somehow got removed from the auto execute list? Is there a grub configuration file I have to edit??

I know that this seems more like a complaint than a technical question, I apologise in advance. Also I'm running CentOS 7 with grub2 here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the configuration file you changed it is hard to figure out what actually happened.

Here are the details on the grub2 `normal` command:

Command: normal [file]

Enter normal mode and display the GRUB menu.

In normal mode, commands, filesystem modules, and cryptography modules are automatically loaded, and the full GRUB script parser is available. Other modules may be explicitly loaded using insmod (see insmod).

If a file is given, then commands will be read from that file. Otherwise, they will be read from $prefix/grub.cfg if it exists.

normal may be called from within normal mode, creating a nested environment. It is more usual to use configfile (see configfile) for this.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the extremely late reply, I have had to type in "normal" into the grub shell every time it boots up for it to take me to the menu. Is there anyway I can create some kind of grub startup script that automatically runs the "normal" command so it just loads the modules and takes me to the menu? Because my grub isn't damaged, it just has this peculiar habit of booting into the prompt. Thanks!